Is it possible to get a c++-doxygen @page displayed into a rst-sphinx doc?
Is it possible to get a c++-doxygen @page displayed into a rst-sphinx doc?
Following this https://sphinx-tutorial.readthedocs.io/start/:
$ git clone https://github.com/ericholscher/pycon-sphinx-tutorial
$ cd pycon-sphinx-tutorial

Now I copy my already documented c++ code that I want to appear in the rst sphinx doc:
pycon-sphinx-tutorial$ cp /path/to/somewhere/function.hpp
pycon-sphinx-tutorial$ cat functions.h 
/**
 * @file    functions.h
 * @author  John DOE
 * @version 1.0
 *
 * @page Functions
 * These functions are meant to be used by the main program.
 */

/**
 * @fn void helloWorld()
 * @brief This function prints a hello world message.
 */
void helloWorld();


Then what I need is to make the doc documented with doxygen in *.hpp (like the @page associated to the function page) to appear in the rst generated documentation: how to do that?
pycon-sphinx-tutorial$ mkdir docs
pycon-sphinx-tutorial$ cd docs
pycon-sphinx-tutorial/docs$ sphinx-quickstart

I add a ref to the Functions page in the index.rst:
pycon-sphinx-tutorial/docs$ cat index.rst 
.. Crawler documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Wed Jun 26 13:41:41 2024.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Crawler's documentation!
===================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   :ref: Functions

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`

pycon-sphinx-tutorial/docs$ make html
...
pycon-sphinx-tutorial/docs/index.rst:9: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document ':ref: Functions'

To fix this error I tried without success to add (the error still shows up when running make html)
pycon-sphinx-tutorial/docs$ cat conf.py
# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('./..'))


Following this https://boschglobal.github.io/doxysphinx/docs/using_rst_in_doxygen.html, I also tried without success to use @rst tags instead of @page:
pycon-sphinx-tutorial/docs$ cat ../functions.h 
/**
 * @file    functions.h
 * @author  John DOE
 * @version 1.0
 *
 * @rst
 * .. Functions
 *    These functions are meant to be used by the main program.
 * @endrst
 */

/**
 * @fn void helloWorld()
 * @brief This function prints a hello world message.
 */
void helloWorld();


All in all, it doesn't work: how to get the c++ doxygen documentation (@page) in the doc generated with rst by sphinx? Is this possible?
